# How to do sum of sum in mysql query

Tags: mysql, sql

```
SELECT a.id AS supplier, sum( processed_weight ) AS total_qty
FROM supplier_inward a
INNER JOIN warehouseb ON a.id = b.supplier
WHERE a.master_product_id = '38'
GROUP BY b.supplier
```

output present

```
supplier    total_qty
12046      475.00
12482      99.00
```

output needed

```
total_qty
574.00
```

here i need the sum(total_qty) in this query? how to achieve this

Comment: Do you need that as an additional row in the same result? Or do you want to run a second SELECT?

Comment: *yup* what? I asked two questions.

Comment: need a additional row in the same result

Comment: based on the current result, you want to add 574.00 as another row? so what about the supplier column? 475 and 99 came from different Supplier. you want to add 475 and 99 and then what value would be displayed in the Supplier Column?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Just modify `GROUP BY`, adding **[`WITH ROLLUP`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/group-by-modifiers.html)**:

```
SELECT a.id AS supplier, sum( processed_weight ) AS total_qty
FROM supplier_inward a
  INNER JOIN warehouseb ON a.id = b.supplier
WHERE a.master_product_id = '38'
GROUP BY b.supplier
  WITH ROLLUP
```

Output:

```
supplier    total_qty
12046       475.00
12482        99.00
NULL        574.00
```

Comment: +1 --I totally missed that MySQL had WITH ROLLUP too! I used it a lot in MSSQL 2005. Works like a charm!

Answer (score 7):

how about this:

```
SELECT SUM(iQuery.total_qty) as iTotal
FROM
    (SELECT a.id AS supplier, sum( processed_weight ) AS total_qty
    FROM supplier_inward a
    INNER JOIN warehouseb ON a.id = b.supplier
    WHERE a.master_product_id = '38'
    GROUP BY b.supplier) as iQuery
```

Answer (score 3):

try

```
SELECT sum( processed_weight ) AS total_qty
FROM supplier_inward a
INNER JOIN warehouseb ON a.id = b.supplier
WHERE a.master_product_id = '38'
```

EDIT 2 - AFTER comment from OP changing the result structure:

For an additional column try:

```
SELECT 
X.supplier,
X.total_qty,
(SELECT sum( processed_weight ) 
 FROM supplier_inward a
 INNER JOIN warehouseb ON a.id = b.supplier
 WHERE a.master_product_id = '38') AS totalq
FROM
(
SELECT 
a.id AS supplier, 
sum( processed_weight ) AS total_qty, 
FROM supplier_inward a
INNER JOIN warehouseb ON a.id = b.supplier
WHERE a.master_product_id = '38'
GROUP BY b.supplier) AS X
```

For an additonal row:

```
SELECT 
a.id AS supplier, 
sum( processed_weight ) AS total_qty
FROM supplier_inward a
INNER JOIN warehouseb ON a.id = b.supplier
WHERE a.master_product_id = '38'
GROUP BY b.supplier
UNION ALL
SELECT null, X.total_qty
FROM
( 
SELECT sum( processed_weight ) AS total_qty
FROM supplier_inward a
INNER JOIN warehouseb ON a.id = b.supplier
WHERE a.master_product_id = '38' ) AS X
```

Answer (score 1):

try without using the group by since you want to sum every thing